# Нужна ли запятая при указании того, в чем измеряется значение?

Tags: пунктуация

ЗОНА ОБОРОНЫ(**,**) % - заголовок.
69.0 - значение.

Я чувствую, что запятая все же нужна. Я отделяю единицу измерения от того, что я измеряю. Так ли это?

Comment: По-русски правильно 69,0.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Я имею в виду перед %

Comment: Не важно, разделитель целой и дробной части по-русски запятая (в английском точка).

Comment: И давно так отделяете? Дайте фразу такой, какой она вам представляется, т.е. без чехарды в порядке и лишних скобок. И учтите комментарий Артёма, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

В заголовках граф и в наименованиях строк **можно** писать обозначения единиц, используя при этом запятую (затем — пробел):
температура, °C;
скорость, км/ч;
относительная влажность, %;
**зона обороны, %**; [значение — 69,0]
среднегодовой прирост, тыс. чел.;
удельная теплопроводность, Вт/(м·К).

Иногда вместо запятой используются скобки (в основном тогда, когда в обозначении единиц имеется несколько слов):
численность населения (млн чел.);
инвестиции (млрд руб.)

[Оформление таблиц (1)](https://www.google.com/search?source=univ&tbm=isch&q=%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%202020&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwii5MrR6truAhXVBhAIHfBRB5sQjJkEegQIAxAB&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=y65ba1J85FUn7M)
[Оформление таблиц (2)](http://doc-style.ru/SPR/?id=1.15)